# How Do I Turn off Google Toolbar's Quick Scroll PERMANENTLY?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9, google-toolbar

I am fed up with the Google Toolbar because it keeps turning on Quick Scroll.  I know how to turn it off via the Tools spanner, then Options, Tools and remove the tick next to 'Quick Scroll'.

[image]

Question: How can I keep this Quick Scroll setting?
Supplementary Question: Which program or website(s) is turning it on?

Comment: I just installed that toolbar for the first time and was unable to instantly replicate the issue. Do you think this could be caused by updates of the toolbar? Meaning, if the toolbar is updated, maybe it resets the setting.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I like your idea of the toolbar update.  Just seen the verion numbers. Version: 7.4.3230.2052/en-GB (GGLL)
Notifier Version: 5.7.7725.1624.  As for replicating the problem, it goes for weeks holding its setting, then suddenly you get 2 or 3 resets in a week.